# SQL Server 2008 R2 Paging with date parameter not returning results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong with this sql code, as it returns no records

```
SELECT *
       FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [ContextId]) AS RowNum
          FROM [dbo].[tblWorkFlow] ) AS WFC
       WHERE WFC.ContextId = @ContextId 
         And WFC.Date = '2014-01-30' 
         And (WFC.RowNum between (
          (@PageNumber-1)*@RecordsPerPage)+1 AND @RecordsPerPage*(@PageNumber)
         )
```

It should return 1 record as this sql shows

```
SELECT  @TotalRecords = (
  Select Count(TblColumnId) 
  FROM [dbo].[tblWorkFlow] 
  WHERE ContextId = @ContextId 
    AND date = @LastModified
)
```

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong

Comment: In case your column is datetime try `AND CONVERT(date, WFC.Date) = '2014-01-30'`

Comment: Hi @Mihai that does not work

Comment: Do a bit of debugging,if you remove And WFC.Date = '2014-01-30' does it return anything?Also edit your question with the parameters used type and value?

Answer (score 0):

Try Thi way

Convert(date,WFC.Date) =  Convert(date,'2014-01-30')

Query Set like this

```
      SELECT * FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [ContextId]) AS RowNum
      FROM [dbo].[tblWorkFlow] ) AS WFC
      WHERE WFC.ContextId = @ContextId and Convert(date,WFC.Date) =  Convert(date,'2014-01-30')
      and (WFC.RowNum between ((@PageNumber-1)*@RecordsPerPage)+1 AND @RecordsPerPage*(@PageNumber))
```

Comment: Sorry for delay in getting back to this, probem is with this line WHERE WFC.ContextId = @ContextId and Convert(date,WFC.Date) =  Convert(date,'2014-01-30') and (WFC.RowNum between ((@PageNumber-1)*@RecordsPerPage)+1 AND @RecordsPerPage*(@PageNumber)) remove the paging section "and Convert(date,WFC.Date) =  Convert(date,'2014-01-30') and (WFC.RowNum between ((@PageNumber-1)*@RecordsPerPage)+1 AND @RecordsPerPage*(@PageNumber))" and it works